# Out Of Memory ao executar um GetFiles em um diretório muito grande

Tags: c#, .net, diretório

Atualmente tenho um diretório com vários subdiretórios que possuem mais de 3 milhões de arquivos. Preciso de mapear somente o diretório onde estão estes arquivos. E esse mapeamento deverá ser separado pelo tipo de arquivo.

O grande problemas estão quando executo um `.GetFiles("*.WAV", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`. Esse comando ficada em média de 40 a 50 minutos executando e depois retorna a exceção `Exceção do tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException' foi acionada.`

Porém no meu servidor tenho atualmente 24 Gb de memória ram.

**DETALHES**

- Estou desenvolvendo essa aplicação em C# Console Application.
- .Net FrameWork 4.5
- O servidor é windows serve 2012

Alguém pode de sugerir uma alternativa para solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o sistema de arquivos de interesse for NTFS, existe uma outra forma de listar esses arquivos de forma realmente muito mais rápida: lendo a [MFT (Master File Table)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS).

[Existe uma resposta já a esta questão no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31931109/195417), na qual vou basear esta resposta.

### Visão geral sobre como ler a Master File Table (MFT)

A leitura da MFT é feita em três passos:

1. verificar se o usuário possui privilégios o suficiente
2. obter um handle para o volume a ser lido (a unidade lógica, e.g C:, D:, etc.)
3. chamar a API do Windows `DeviceIOControl` em loop para enumerar os arquivos

Cada um desses passos merece mais do que uma resposta inteira, então vou me limitar a descrever o que está acontecendo de forma bem superficial em cada um.

No programa abaixo, estão marcados onde os passos ocorrem.

O método `ProcessEntry` recebe cada entrada a ser processada.

**Program.cs**

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // passo 1
        if (!Privileges.HasBackupAndRestorePrivileges)
            Console.WriteLine("Could not assert privileges");

        // passo 2
        using (var volume = WinFiles.GetVolumeHandle(@"\\.\C:"))
            try
            {
                // passo 3
                WinFiles.ReadMft(volume, ProcessEntry);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
    }

    private static void ProcessEntry(NativeMethods.UsnRecord usnRecord)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FRN:" + usnRecord.FileReferenceNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Parent FRN:" + usnRecord.ParentFileReferenceNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("File name:" + usnRecord.FileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Attributes: "
            + (NativeMethods.EFileAttributes)usnRecord.FileAttributes);
        Console.WriteLine("Timestamp:" + usnRecord.TimeStamp);
    }
}
```

### Verificar privilégios

A verificação de privilégios se dá tentando liberar o privilégio para o [Token de Acesso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909(v=vs.85).aspx) do processo, através do método [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202(v=vs.85).aspx). Se esse método não falhar, quer dizer que o usuário possui o privilégio em questão, e a partir desse momento o processo pode se valer desse privilégio.

Os privilégios necessários são `"SeBackupPrivilege"` e `"SeRestorePrivilege"`. Administradores e operadores de backup possuem esses privilégios, por exemplo.

**Privilleges.cs**

```
public static class Privileges
{
    private static int asserted;
    private static bool hasBackupPrivileges;

    public static bool HasBackupAndRestorePrivileges => AssertPriveleges();

    /// <remarks>
    /// First time this method is called, it attempts to set
    /// backup privileges for the current process.
    /// Subsequently, it returns the results of that first call.
    /// </remarks>
    private static bool AssertPriveleges()
    {
        var wasAsserted = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref asserted, 1, 0);
        if (wasAsserted == 0)  // first time here?  come on in!
        {
            var success = AssertPrivelege(NativeMethods.SE_BACKUP_NAME)
                           && AssertPrivelege(NativeMethods.SE_RESTORE_NAME);

            hasBackupPrivileges = success;
        }
        return hasBackupPrivileges;
    }


    private static bool AssertPrivelege(string privelege)
    {
        IntPtr token;
        if (!NativeMethods.OpenProcessToken(
                NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcess(),
                NativeMethods.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
                out token))
            return false;

        try
        {
            var tokenPrivileges = new NativeMethods.TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
            {
                Privileges = new NativeMethods.LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1]
            };

            if (!NativeMethods.LookupPrivilegeValue(
                    null,
                    privelege,
                    out tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid))
                return false;

            tokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes
                = NativeMethods.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
            if (!NativeMethods.AdjustTokenPrivileges(
                    token,
                    false,
                    ref tokenPrivileges,
                    Marshal.SizeOf(tokenPrivileges),
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    IntPtr.Zero))
                return false;

            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0)
                return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            NativeMethods.CloseHandle(token);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

### Obter handle do volume

Esse handle é obtido através do método [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx). Iremos passar o diretório raiz do volume que desejamos listar, por exemplo o `C:` assim: `\\.\C:`. Além disso, abriremos o arquivo para leitura (`GenericRead`) em modo de backup (`BackupSemantics`).

O código do método que lê o handle está logo abaixo, no arquivo `WinFiles.cs`.

### Ler a MFT

Finalmente usamos o método `DeviceIOControl` para obter os registros da MFT. Esse é um método polivalente que recebe uma enorme gama de inputs e devolve também outra enorme gama de outputs dependendo do código de controle passado.

Na verdade vamos usar o USN Journal, que lista todas as alterações feitas no volume, e enumerar as entradas da MFT a partir dessa lista, pois os cada alteração registrada aponta para o arquivo na MFT.

Os elementos do [USN Journal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal) podem apontar para arquivos que não existem mais e elementos duplicados. Mas não teremos de nos preocupar com isso pois usaremos o código de controle [`FSCTL_ENUM_USN_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364563(v=vs.85).aspx), que retorna somente entradas da MFT.

**WinFiles.cs**

```
internal static class WinFiles
{
    public static SafeFileHandle GetVolumeHandle(
        string pathToVolume)
    {
        var handle = NativeMethods.CreateFile(
            pathToVolume,
            NativeMethods.EFileAccess.GenericRead,
            FileShare.Read | FileShare.Write | FileShare.Delete,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            (uint)NativeMethods.ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting,
            (uint)NativeMethods.EFileAttributes.BackupSemantics,
            IntPtr.Zero);

        if (handle.IsInvalid)
            throw new IOException("Bad path");

        return handle;
    }

    public static unsafe void ReadMft(
        SafeHandle volume,
        Action<NativeMethods.UsnRecordV2> processEntry)
    {
        var input = new NativeMethods.MFTEnumDataV0
        {
            StartFileReferenceNumber = 0,
            LowUsn = 0,
            HighUsn = long.MaxValue
        };
        var usnRecord = new NativeMethods.UsnRecordV2();
        var outputBuffer = new byte[1024 * 1024];

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(outputBuffer, true))
            while (true)
                fixed (byte* pOutput = outputBuffer)
                {
                    uint bytesRead;
                    var okay = NativeMethods.DeviceIoControl
                        (
                            volume.DangerousGetHandle(),
                            NativeMethods.DeviceIOControlCode.FsctlEnumUsnData,
                            (byte*)&input,
                            (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(input),
                            pOutput,
                            (uint)outputBuffer.Length,
                            out bytesRead,
                            IntPtr.Zero
                        );

                    if (!okay)
                    {
                        var error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        if (error != NativeMethods.ERROR_HANDLE_EOF)
                            throw new Win32Exception(error);

                        break;
                    }

                    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true))
                        input.StartFileReferenceNumber = reader.ReadUInt64();
                    while (stream.Position < bytesRead)
                    {
                        usnRecord.Read(stream);
                        processEntry(usnRecord);
                    }
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }
    }
}
```

### Dependências

**NativeMethods.cs**

```
internal class NativeMethods
{
    internal const int ERROR_HANDLE_EOF = 38;

    //--> Privilege constants....
    internal const UInt32 SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
    internal const string SE_BACKUP_NAME = "SeBackupPrivilege";
    internal const string SE_RESTORE_NAME = "SeRestorePrivilege";
    internal const string SE_SECURITY_NAME = "SeSecurityPrivilege";
    internal const string SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME = "SeChangeNotifyPrivilege";
    internal const string SE_CREATE_SYMBOLIC_LINK_NAME = "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege";
    internal const string SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_NAME = "SeCreatePermanentPrivilege";
    internal const string SE_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_NAME = "SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege";
    internal const string SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME = "SeSystemtimePrivilege";
    internal const string SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME = "SeTimeZonePrivilege";
    internal const string SE_TCB_NAME = "SeTcbPrivilege";
    internal const string SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME = "SeManageVolumePrivilege";
    internal const string SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME = "SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege";

    //--> For starting a process in session 1 from session 0...
    internal const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    internal const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;
    internal const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;
    internal const uint TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
    internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpSystemName, string lpName, out LUID lpLuid);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr TokenHandle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool DisableAllPrivileges, ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES NewState, Int32 BufferLength, IntPtr PreviousState, IntPtr ReturnLength);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static unsafe extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, DeviceIOControlCode controlCode, byte* lpInBuffer, uint nInBufferSize, byte* lpOutBuffer, uint nOutBufferSize, out uint lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, EFileAccess dwDesiredAccess, FileShare dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);


    [Flags]
    internal enum EMethod : uint
    {
        Buffered = 0,
        InDirect = 1,
        OutDirect = 2,
        Neither = 3
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum EFileAccess : uint
    {
        GenericRead = 0x80000000,
        GenericWrite = 0x40000000,
        GenericExecute = 0x20000000,
        GenericAll = 0x10000000,

        Delete = 0x10000,
        ReadControl = 0x20000,
        WriteDAC = 0x40000,
        WriteOwner = 0x80000,
        Synchronize = 0x100000,

        StandardRightsRequired = 0xF0000,
        StandardRightsRead = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsWrite = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsExecute = ReadControl,
        StandardRightsAll = 0x1F0000,
        SpecificRightsAll = 0xFFFF,

        AccessSystemSecurity = 0x1000000,
        MaximumAllowed = 0x2000000
    }


    [Flags]
    internal enum EFileDevice : uint
    {
        Beep = 0x00000001,
        CDRom = 0x00000002,
        CDRomFileSytem = 0x00000003,
        Controller = 0x00000004,
        Datalink = 0x00000005,
        Dfs = 0x00000006,
        Disk = 0x00000007,
        DiskFileSystem = 0x00000008,
        FileSystem = 0x00000009,
        InPortPort = 0x0000000a,
        Keyboard = 0x0000000b,
        Mailslot = 0x0000000c,
        MidiIn = 0x0000000d,
        MidiOut = 0x0000000e,
        Mouse = 0x0000000f,
        MultiUncProvider = 0x00000010,
        NamedPipe = 0x00000011,
        Network = 0x00000012,
        NetworkBrowser = 0x00000013,
        NetworkFileSystem = 0x00000014,
        Null = 0x00000015,
        ParallelPort = 0x00000016,
        PhysicalNetcard = 0x00000017,
        Printer = 0x00000018,
        Scanner = 0x00000019,
        SerialMousePort = 0x0000001a,
        SerialPort = 0x0000001b,
        Screen = 0x0000001c,
        Sound = 0x0000001d,
        Streams = 0x0000001e,
        Tape = 0x0000001f,
        TapeFileSystem = 0x00000020,
        Transport = 0x00000021,
        Unknown = 0x00000022,
        Video = 0x00000023,
        VirtualDisk = 0x00000024,
        WaveIn = 0x00000025,
        WaveOut = 0x00000026,
        Port8042 = 0x00000027,
        NetworkRedirector = 0x00000028,
        Battery = 0x00000029,
        BusExtender = 0x0000002a,
        Modem = 0x0000002b,
        Vdm = 0x0000002c,
        MassStorage = 0x0000002d,
        Smb = 0x0000002e,
        Ks = 0x0000002f,
        Changer = 0x00000030,
        Smartcard = 0x00000031,
        Acpi = 0x00000032,
        Dvd = 0x00000033,
        FullscreenVideo = 0x00000034,
        DfsFileSystem = 0x00000035,
        DfsVolume = 0x00000036,
        Serenum = 0x00000037,
        Termsrv = 0x00000038,
        Ksec = 0x00000039,
        // From Windows Driver Kit 7
        Fips = 0x0000003A,
        Infiniband = 0x0000003B,
        Vmbus = 0x0000003E,
        CryptProvider = 0x0000003F,
        Wpd = 0x00000040,
        Bluetooth = 0x00000041,
        MtComposite = 0x00000042,
        MtTransport = 0x00000043,
        Biometric = 0x00000044,
        Pmi = 0x00000045
    }

    internal enum EFileIOCtlAccess : uint
    {
        Any = 0,
        Special = Any,
        Read = 1,
        Write = 2
    }

    internal enum DeviceIOControlCode : uint
    {
        FsctlEnumUsnData = (EFileDevice.FileSystem << 16) | (44 << 2) | EMethod.Neither | (EFileIOCtlAccess.Any << 14),
        FsctlReadUsnJournal = (EFileDevice.FileSystem << 16) | (46 << 2) | EMethod.Neither | (EFileIOCtlAccess.Any << 14),
        FsctlReadFileUsnData = (EFileDevice.FileSystem << 16) | (58 << 2) | EMethod.Neither | (EFileIOCtlAccess.Any << 14),
        FsctlQueryUsnJournal = (EFileDevice.FileSystem << 16) | (61 << 2) | EMethod.Buffered | (EFileIOCtlAccess.Any << 14),
        FsctlCreateUsnJournal = (EFileDevice.FileSystem << 16) | (57 << 2) | EMethod.Neither | (EFileIOCtlAccess.Any << 14)
    }

    /// <summary>Control structure used to interrogate MFT data using DeviceIOControl from the user volume</summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct MFTEnumDataV0
    {
        public ulong StartFileReferenceNumber;
        public long LowUsn;
        public long HighUsn;
    }


    /// <summary>A structure resurned form USN queries</summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// FileName is synthetic...composed during a read of the structure and is not technically
    /// part of the Win32 API's definition...although the actual FileName is contained
    /// "somewhere" in the structure's trailing bytes, according to FileNameLength and FileNameOffset.
    /// 
    /// Alignment boundaries are enforced, and so, the RecordLength
    /// may be somewhat larger than the accumulated lengths of the members plus the FileNameLength.
    /// </remarks>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct UsnRecord
    {
        public uint RecordLength;
        public ushort MajorVersion;
        public ushort MinorVersion;
        public ulong FileReferenceNumber;
        public ulong ParentFileReferenceNumber;
        public long Usn;
        public long TimeStamp;
        public UsnReason Reason;
        public uint SourceInfo;
        public uint SecurityId;
        public uint FileAttributes;
        public ushort FileNameLength;
        public ushort FileNameOffset;
        public string FileName;

        /// <remarks>Note how the read advances to the FileNameOffset and reads only FileNameLength bytes</remarks>
        public void Read(Stream stream)
        {
            var startOfRecord = stream.Position;

            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true))
            {
                this.RecordLength = reader.ReadUInt32();
                this.MajorVersion = reader.ReadUInt16();
                this.MinorVersion = reader.ReadUInt16();
                this.FileReferenceNumber = reader.ReadUInt64();
                this.ParentFileReferenceNumber = reader.ReadUInt64();
                this.Usn = reader.ReadInt64();
                this.TimeStamp = reader.ReadInt64();
                this.Reason = (UsnReason)reader.ReadUInt32();
                this.SourceInfo = reader.ReadUInt32();
                this.SecurityId = reader.ReadUInt32();
                this.FileAttributes = reader.ReadUInt32();
                this.FileNameLength = reader.ReadUInt16();
                this.FileNameOffset = reader.ReadUInt16();

                stream.Position = startOfRecord + this.FileNameOffset;
                this.FileName = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(this.FileNameLength));

                stream.Position = startOfRecord + this.RecordLength;
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct LUID
    {
        public UInt32 LowPart;
        public Int32 HighPart;
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public LUID Luid;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
    }


    internal struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    {
        public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]      // !! think we only need one
        public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum EFileAttributes : uint
    {
        /// <summary/>
        None = 0,

        //-->  these are consistent w/ .Net FileAttributes...
        Readonly = 0x00000001,
        Hidden = 0x00000002,
        System = 0x00000004,
        Directory = 0x00000010,
        Archive = 0x00000020,
        Device = 0x00000040,
        Normal = 0x00000080,
        Temporary = 0x00000100,
        SparseFile = 0x00000200,
        ReparsePoint = 0x00000400,
        Compressed = 0x00000800,
        Offline = 0x00001000,
        NotContentIndexed = 0x00002000,
        Encrypted = 0x00004000,

        //--> additional CreateFile call attributes...
        Write_Through = 0x80000000,
        Overlapped = 0x40000000,
        NoBuffering = 0x20000000,
        RandomAccess = 0x10000000,
        SequentialScan = 0x08000000,
        DeleteOnClose = 0x04000000,
        BackupSemantics = 0x02000000,
        PosixSemantics = 0x01000000,
        OpenReparsePoint = 0x00200000,
        OpenNoRecall = 0x00100000,
        FirstPipeInstance = 0x00080000
    }

    /// <summary>Reasons the file changed (from USN journal)</summary>
    [Flags]
    public enum UsnReason : uint
    {
        BASIC_INFO_CHANGE = 0x00008000,
        CLOSE = 0x80000000,
        COMPRESSION_CHANGE = 0x00020000,
        DATA_EXTEND = 0x00000002,
        DATA_OVERWRITE = 0x00000001,
        DATA_TRUNCATION = 0x00000004,
        EA_CHANGE = 0x00000400,
        ENCRYPTION_CHANGE = 0x00040000,
        FILE_CREATE = 0x00000100,
        FILE_DELETE = 0x00000200,
        HARD_LINK_CHANGE = 0x00010000,
        INDEXABLE_CHANGE = 0x00004000,
        NAMED_DATA_EXTEND = 0x00000020,
        NAMED_DATA_OVERWRITE = 0x00000010,
        NAMED_DATA_TRUNCATION = 0x00000040,
        OBJECT_ID_CHANGE = 0x00080000,
        RENAME_NEW_NAME = 0x00002000,
        RENAME_OLD_NAME = 0x00001000,
        REPARSE_POINT_CHANGE = 0x00100000,
        SECURITY_CHANGE = 0x00000800,
        STREAM_CHANGE = 0x00200000,

        None = 0x00000000
    }

    internal enum ECreationDisposition : uint
    {
        New = 1,
        CreateAlways = 2,
        OpenExisting = 3,
        OpenAlways = 4,
        TruncateExisting = 5
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimente trocar por [`EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx). Ele faz isto de forma mais eficiente.

Mas precisa ver se o problema é este mesmo. Já mediu para ter certeza que é aí? Será que isto não está fazendo múltiplas vezes? Sem ter certeza de onde é o problema fica difícil consertá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx)

> O EnumerateFiles e GetFiles métodos diferenciam da seguinte maneira:
>   quando você usa EnumerateFiles, você pode começar a enumerar a coleção
>   de nomes antes da coleção inteira será retornada; Quando você usa
>   GetFiles, você deve aguardar a matriz inteira de nomes a serem
>   retornadas para poder acessar a matriz.Portanto, quando você estiver
>   trabalhando com muitos arquivos e diretórios, EnumerateFiles pode ser
>   mais eficiente.

Ainda pode se aproveitar do `Take` para paginar o retorno dos arquivos :

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
            IEnumerable<FileInfo> files;

files = from file in di.EnumerateFiles("*.WAV", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        select file;                                          

                return files.Take(100);
```

Fonte : https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Quando faço `take(100)` e depois faço outro `take(100)` ele vai buscar os 100 primeiro registros, e depois mais 100. Ou sempre vai retornar os mesmos?

Comment: Sim o Take pega os mesmos. No meu caso, os arquivos eram movidos após o processamento, então tudo bem. Mas se no seu caso os arquivos continuam na pasta, use em conjunto com o Take o método Skip https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx.